# What are the reasons that a Spring @async annotation may have failed to fire?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, annotations

We're got some code annotated with the Spring [@async annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) - which is meant to run the method in a new Thread.  In theory - this method should run on startup.

In practice - it is not running at all.

```
package ...
...
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
...
@Component
public class MyClass {
...
    @Async
    public void mymethod() {
    ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to think of all the possible reasons this could be:

- class not in Spring component scan path (not in this case - checked)

My question is: **What are the reasons that a Spring @async annotation may have failed to fire?**

(Is there a class I can log in case the async execute was attempted and failed?)

Comment: And why should the `@ASync` run on startup. There is nothing in there making that clear. Also when something should run on startup generally using an init method is the wrong approach. Why? Because AOP might not have yet been applied rendering things like `@Async` or `@Transactional` useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the situation where `@Async` was not working for me

1. `@EnableAsync` was missing
2. `@Async` method was not public
3. `@Async` annotated method was called from another method of same class. Probably bypassing the **async** proxy code and just calling plain method.